# Reapplying for the F-1 visa from the UK as a foreigner

Tags: usa, uk, f1-visas, student-visas

Is it possible to apply for the F-1 visa to the US from the UK? I have no UK citizenship, nor Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK. I plan to apply for the UK visitor visa first and re-apply for the F-1 visa to the US, as US embassies in my country are closed now.

Comment: For completeness, does re-apply indicate an expired F-1 or a refusal?

Comment: What does your academic institution recommend?

Comment: This site is about short term travel like vacations. Questions about living and studying abroad belong on our [expatriates.se] site.

Comment: Requests not made on home countries are always looked with suspect (people try to do visa shop). You should have a very good reason, and better documentation (and probably it will be checked also in your home country [e.g. because of study diplomas]). So, if you had a refusal; chances are very low, and it will just lower chances for future visas. -- but legally you can apply in any US embassies/ US consular offices.

Comment: Hi Giacomo. I am forced to apply from abroad because the US embassy in my home country will be closed this and next years. I had no refusals in the past

Comment: Close voters: F-1 visas can be used for short-term studies e.g. 10 weeks. No need to become expat.

Comment: If you're not from the EU/Schengen/UK, I wouldn't recommend going to an EU/Schengen/UK country for a US visa in 2020 while the proclamation banning travel within 14 days from these countries to the US is in effect... Maybe try a country closer to your home country instead.

Comment: If it is for a long term visa, I am happy to move it to Expats, just ping me.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to apply for the F-1 visa to the US from the UK? I have no UK citizenship

Yes. See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/8013/164 by [Michael Hampton](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/790/michael-hampton):

> The US does not restrict where you may apply for a *nonimmigrant* visa
> (such as a student visa) from. You may do so in any country you've
> legally entered, even if as a tourist.
>
> [From the US State Department: travel.state.gov > Visas > Study and Exchange > Student Visa](https://web.archive.org/web/20171124133801/https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student.html):
>
> > You must schedule an appointment for your visa interview, generally, at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You
> > may schedule your interview at any U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be
> > aware that it may be difficult to qualify for a visa outside of your
> > place of permanent residence.